# If a cell value is changed, change cell value next to it

Tags: vba, excel

I need to clear a dependant dropdown `b2` when `a2` value is changed by the user. I have 518 values that need this code, (if `a2` is changed, blank `b2`, if `a3` is changed blank `a3`, if `a4` is changed blank `a4`, etc..).

What is the easiest way to do this? Here is my code to change one value (there must be a more efficient way than copying this code 518 times). Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("a2").Address Then
        Range("b2").Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.row` property of the target range, and apply that to the `Cells()` method of grabbing your range to change.

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim tgtRng As Range
    Set tgtRng = Range("A:A")

    If Intersect(tgtRng, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = vbNullString

End Sub
```

Comment: Why `Exit Sub` instead of just using the `If`?

Comment: Thanks for that sharp eye @SJR. Tom - if he had multiple events to handle, I would have gone with the If statement. Either way works I suppose.

Comment: Or a one-liner `if target.column=1 then target.offset(,1).clear`. Personal preference I guess. Plus you never know what other code there might be.

Comment: Works great! Thanks very much!